# Routing in Spring Integration DSL

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I was working with the following IntegrationFlow form, where I was filtering my topic messages by a header value by means of:

```
IntegrationFlows.from ( 
                        Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter (  Jms.container(factory, connection)
                                                              .messageSelector("X-HEADER = 'X_VALUE'")
                                                              .get() 
                                                        )
                           .get()
                      )
                .handle(XMessageHandler)
                .get();
```

..or either

```
IntegrationFlows.from ( 
                        Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter (  Jms.container(factory, connection)
                                                              .get() 
                                                        )
                           .get()
                      )
                .filter(Message.class, filterByHeaderPropertySelector(X_HEADER, X_VALUE)
                .handle(XMessageHandler)
                .get();
```

But now, a new type of expected flow has joined the topic, so the discriminator header has a new value Y. So a new filter `filter(Message.class, filterByHeaderPropertySelector(Y_HEADER, Y_VALUE)` with target to `YMessageHandler`.

My problem is how can I reuse the infrastructure with minimum impact. It would be ideal to use filter with routing, but `route` operation does not seem to be inlined in the same way. Perhaps is there an easier/obvious way?

Also, should I duplicate the adapter for each message selector? What's the difference between putting the Message Selector in the very container setting or doing it as part of the integration flow. Is there any performance hit or does the integration builder optimizes it smartly? I mean, it could very well happen that putting the selector on the flow does not avoid to parse the message and such, whereas on the definition of the container it just filters it from the beginning. What's the best approach to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution, of course, will be the selector on the container. That way message filtering is done on the Broker.

Any way you have to take a look to the `Router` in addition and consult the header for the current value to chose the proper downstream channel.

The filter is kind of binary router, but any way would be better to implement the logic with router: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#routers

**UPDATE**

Sub-flow mapping sample:

```
.<Integer, Boolean>route(p -> p % 2 == 0, m -> m
        .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 2))
        .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 3)))
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly the info i needed!

Comment: Wait, the thing is I need to process all kind of messages on my client. So I don't mind receiveing all messages as long as I route them. In that case, is there any benefit of using the container approach? I guess I should go for router. Also is there anyway to work directly with handlers in route instead of creating channels?

Comment: You need container any way to get messages from the broker. But if you don't care about their type, you shouldn't use selector there. Would be much better for performance. All the rest logic should be implemented in router and all the downstream branch flows

Comment: There is. It is called sub-flow mapping.

Comment: So then, if I need to capture all events anyway, and I have a header discriminator, each value associated to a MessageHandler (with several ServiceActivators), the best option should be sub-flow mapping. Is it ok?

Comment: I think so. See an UPDATE in my answer

Comment: That's really great! Just a final question, is there a way to put something like HeaderValueRouter in place of "p -> p % 2 == 0" ? Does not seem to fit

Comment: You can use like this `route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeader((X_HEADER), r -> ...)` or `route("headers[X_HEADER]", r -> ...)`